# Google Ad Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-ads-script

I have a Google Ads script which pulls close variant keyword performance if it is above a ROAS threshold, and then exports it to a google sheet every 30 days. I'm then looking for a way for the script to take the keyword and ad group data and loop through the sheets, lookup the keywords and return the quality scores for these keywords after I have added them.

Here's my below code, I'm struggling with adding to a 2D array from the Google sheet (as you need a 2d array to look up keywords). I also need to be able to push the data back to the sheet. Any thoughts please?

```
    var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheetUrl).getSheets();

    for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
       var sheet = sheets[i];
       var data_range = sheet.getDataRange();
       var last_row = data_range.getLastRow();

          for(var r=2;r<=last_row;r++) {
            var list = [];
            var keywordID = [];
            var adGroupId = [];
            var keywordID = data_range.getCell(r,13).getValue();
            var adGroupId = data_range.getCell(r,14).getValue();
            list.push([adGroupId,keywordID]);

              var keywords = AdsApp.keywords().withIds(list).get();
         
                while (keywords.hasNext()) {
                  var keyword = keywords.next();
                  var stats = [];
                  var stats = keyword.getQualityScore();
                  row_array.push(stats);
                  sheet.appendRow(row_array)  
                     }

        }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

`var data_range = sheet.getDataRange();` is your 2D range

`var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();` is your 2D array

You can loop through the data this way (no need the `last_row`):

```
for(var r=2; r<=data.length; r++)
```

Then

```
var keywordID = data[r][13]; // or [12], I don't know
var adGroupId = data[r][14]; // or [13]
```

Probably it would look about like this

```
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheetUrl).getSheets();

for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
  var sheet = sheets[i];
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  for (var r = 2; r <= data.length; r++) {
    var keywordID = data[r][13]; // or [12]
    var adGroupId = data[r][14]; // or [13]
    var keywords = AdsApp.keywords().withIds([adGroupId, keywordID]).get(); // ?

    var row_array = []
    while (keywords.hasNext()) {
      var stats = keywords.next().getQualityScore();
      row_array.push(stats);
    }
    sheet.appendRow(row_array);
  }
}
```

I haven't tested it since I have no your data and not quite understand the task.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is almost working now. The line var keywords = AdsApp.keywords().withIds([adGroupId, keywordID]).get(); // ? needs to be a 2D array so I have added a push method to push adgroupId and keywordID to another array which is working when I use logger.log to check. However I'm getting the error message TypeError: Cannot read property "12" from undefined. (file Code.gs, line 149). Any ideas?

Comment: The error is on the var keywordId line - why would it not be reading the 12 as a column position?

Comment: `data[r][13]` is array. Its elements counts from zero. So `0` is first column, `1` is second column, etc. So probably your 13th column is 12th element of the array. Try [12] and [13] (instead of [13] and [14]) respectively. And I suspect there are another errors as well. For example I have no idea if will work `AdsApp.keywords().withIds([adGroupId, keywordID]).get()` it looks rather wrong.